# Test $x^4 - 9x^3 + 9x^2 +81x - 162$ for multiple roots.

Tags: linear-algebra

The question requires me to test the equation for multiple roots.

**My Approach**: I tried using $f'(x)$ to find the HCF. However, the process becomes quite long and cumbersome and neither does it give me an suitable HCF. The remainder is in fractions which means dividing the divisor by it in the second step becomes even more cumbersome as the remainder has a large fraction.

Comment: This polynomial is $(x-6)(x-3)^2(x+3)$. A computer algebra system tells you that, and this information guides you to the only repeated root.

Comment: We have
$$f(3x)=3^4(x^4-3x^3+x^2+3x-2).$$
So if you are bothered by the numbers becoming cumbersome, you can do the same with $g(x)=x^4-3x^3+x^2+3x-2$ and $g'(x)$ instead of $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that at $x=3$ both the function and its derivative $4x^3-27x^2+18x+81$ are equal to zero. Therefore 3 is a repeated root.

Answer (score 1):

well, there is a method  for gcd of polynomials, same as for numbers

$$  \left(   x^{4}  - 9 x^{3}  + 9 x^{2}  + 81 x  - 162 \right)  $$

$$  \left(  4 x^{3}  - 27 x^{2}  + 18 x  + 81 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{4}  - 9 x^{3}  + 9 x^{2}  + 81 x  - 162 \right)  =  \left(  4 x^{3}  - 27 x^{2}  + 18 x  + 81 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 4 x  - 9 }{ 16 }  \right) } +  \left(   \frac{  - 171 x^{2}  + 1134 x  - 1863 }{ 16 }  \right)  $$
$$  \left(  4 x^{3}  - 27 x^{2}  + 18 x  + 81 \right)  =  \left(   \frac{  - 171 x^{2}  + 1134 x  - 1863 }{ 16 }  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 1216 x  + 144 }{ 3249 }  \right) } +  \left(   \frac{  - 10368 x  + 31104 }{ 361 }  \right)  $$
$$  \left(   \frac{  - 171 x^{2}  + 1134 x  - 1863 }{ 16 }  \right)  =  \left(   \frac{  - 10368 x  + 31104 }{ 361 }  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 6859 x  - 24909 }{ 18432 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$
$$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$
$$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$
$$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 4 x  - 9 }{ 16 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 4 x  - 9 }{ 16 }  \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$
$$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 1216 x  + 144 }{ 3249 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  - 304 x^{2}  + 720 x  + 3168 }{ 3249 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{  - 1216 x  + 144 }{ 3249 }  \right) } $$
$$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 6859 x  - 24909 }{ 18432 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  - 361 x^{3}  + 2166 x^{2}  + 3249 x  - 19494 }{ 10368 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{  - 1444 x^{2}  + 5415 x  + 9747 }{ 10368 }  \right) } $$
$$  \left(   x^{3}  - 6 x^{2}  - 9 x  + 54 \right)  \left(   \frac{  - 76 x  + 9 }{ 5832 }  \right)  -  \left(  4 x^{2}  - 15 x  - 27 \right)  \left(   \frac{  - 19 x^{2}  + 45 x  + 198 }{ 5832 }  \right)  =  \left( 1  \right)  $$
$$  \mbox{confirming  GCD} =   \color{blue}{  \left(   x  - 3 \right) }   $$
$$  \left(   x^{4}  - 9 x^{3}  + 9 x^{2}  + 81 x  - 162 \right)  =  \left(   x^{3}  - 6 x^{2}  - 9 x  + 54 \right)  \cdot \color{blue}{  \left(   x  - 3 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$
$$  \left(  4 x^{3}  - 27 x^{2}  + 18 x  + 81 \right)  =  \left(  4 x^{2}  - 15 x  - 27 \right)  \cdot \color{blue}{  \left(   x  - 3 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$
$$  \left(   x^{4}  - 9 x^{3}  + 9 x^{2}  + 81 x  - 162 \right)  \left(   \frac{  - 76 x  + 9 }{ 5832 }  \right)  -  \left(  4 x^{3}  - 27 x^{2}  + 18 x  + 81 \right)  \left(   \frac{  - 19 x^{2}  + 45 x  + 198 }{ 5832 }  \right)  =  \color{blue}{  \left(   x  - 3 \right)  } $$
$$  \mbox{GCD} =   \color{blue}{  \left(   x  - 3 \right) }   $$

Answer (score 1):

There is a more direct way to find multiple roots of a polynomial, which is to find all the roots. For a biquadratic polynomial (fourth-degree polynomial), the best way is to guess the roots and verify if they are. Observe from the polynomial that if the root is an integer, it should be divisible by $3$.

If $f(x) = x^4 - 9x^3 + 9x^2 +81x - 162$, then, $f(3) = 0$ and $f(6) = 0$. So, the polynomial $f(x)$ is divisible by both $(x-3)$ and $(x-6)$, and so their product is too. Dividing the polynomial with this product will yield $x^2 - 9$ as the quotient, whose roots are obviously $3$ and $-3$. So, $3$ is the multiple root of this polynomial.

In case you wish to solve by the derivative method, observe that $f'(x) = 4x^3 - 27x^2 + 18x + 81$, and $f'(3) = 0$, which means that $3$ is a potential multiple root of $f(x)$ and that $(x-3)$ divides $f'(x)$. Dividing $f'(x)$ by $(x-3)$ gives $4x^2 - 15x - 27$. Now, you can divide $f(x)$ with $4x^2 - 15x - 27$ to get some remainder. The roots of $4x^2 - 15x - 27$ could also be potential multiple roots. However, observe that dividing $f(x)$ with $4x^2 - 15x - 27$ will give a linear polynomial as remainder with rational coefficients and the roots of $4x^2 - 15x - 27$ are irrational, so for neither of the roots the remainder would be zero (One does need to check if the remainder is exactly zero, which it isn't). Thus, these roots are not actually potential double roots. Now, just check if $f(x)$ is divisible by $x^2 - 6x + 9$, which it will be, and thus, $3$ is a multiple root of $f(x)$.